# comparable word to soundtrack but with reference to movies/visuals?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

what is the comparable word to soundtrack but with reference to movies/visuals?  The phrase is the "soundtrack of my childhood" but I want it to be the "movie track" of my childhood...Thanks.

Comment: Not very inventive: **Childhood memories of movies**.

Comment: You might not be able to do better than a 'hypernym' of a lexical gap, a _record_.

Comment: *Video stream*?

Answer (score 1):

***Images*** of my childhood will give you the visual.  Movies implies both audio and visual.  If you want that memories should do.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to movies, I think you can use *stills* as ***Stills of my childhood.***

Answer (score 0):

But we want moving pictures, right?  Not just a slide show/powerpoint?  So I'll suggest

*the **screenplay** of my childhood*